# Transfer operation,why the gaslimit is not the same

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

Everything else is the same, the address is different, why the gaslimit is not the same?

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: First, can you give the context od your operation? Is this mist? Second, what are those 2 addresses ? EOA, or contracts? If those are contracts, are you sure there are the same ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain you'll find that the first address above has no balance of SSS tokens, whereas the second address already has a balance of tokens.

Why so?

- To set a storage location (e.g. the balance of an address in a token contract) from zero to a value costs 20000 gas. I think this is happening in your first case.
- To change a storage location from one non-zero value to another non-zero value costs only 5000 gas. I think this is happening in your second case.

The difference is 15k gas, exactly what you are seeing above.

If I could cut and paste the addresses, I'd check for myself...

Comment: Yes. One address has SSS and the other is not

Comment: Great. If you are satisfied that this is the correct explanation, then it's good to mark the answer as accepted, for the benefit of others.